# Property is not defined for type when i want to build expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I Want to build an expression to query into my database by EF Core 2.1

I have my `Data` class that represent entity from my table:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Id1 {get;set;}
    public string Id2 {get;set;}
}
```

Then i want to build some expression:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Data), "x");
var memberId1 = Expression.Field(parameter, nameof(Data.Id1));
var memberId2 = Expression.Field(parameter, nameof(Data.Id2));
```

When i want to make `Field` from `Id1`, i get this expcetion:

> System.ArgumentException: Instance field 'Id1' is not defined for type 'Entities.Data'
>       at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Field(Expression expression, String fieldName)

How to get acces intoo field from my `Data` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `Id1` and `Id2` is not Field but `Property`. Now it works:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Data), "x");
var memberId1 = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(Data.Id1));
var memberId2 = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(Data.Id2));
```

Comment: This is correct - and you definitely *don't* need to create an instance as Jazimov's answer claims.

Comment: Thank you, that'll teach me to try to answer a question at 3 AM. :) I deleted my answer so as not to cause any further confusion. I had misunderstood the reported error message and leapt to a suggestion that would have produced the same error because nameof(Data.Id1) would produce the same result as nameof(data.Id1), where the former uses the Data type and the latter uses the data instance. Thanks for setting me straight.